# Initial SVN Checkout Fails: "access forbidden" in Terminal, "Error 403" in browser

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I have been trying to set up an svn repository on an ubuntu 11.04 machine using apache2 as the server. I was able to build the VirtualHost, get it started, create the svn repository, set up the SSL and access the svn repository locally.

However, for the last 1.5 days I've been trying to figure how to check it out to check it out from a different machine using svn checkout with a user I previously created for the svn. When I try to check out in the terminal, I get the following error:

```
svn: access to '<Location>' forbidden
```

On the other hand, if I go to my browser, I get a 403 Error saying:

```
You don't have permission to access /svn/TSAACode on this server.
```

Now, I have scoured google, stackoverflow, linux forums and my grand mother's attick and not been able to find a solution. I have a hunch that it has something to do with permissions SVN directory (which I set to 777), or maybe something with the server not being allowed to read the files.

Here are some of the important files:

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

    DocumentRoot /svn/Code/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /svn/Code/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /etc/apache2/logs/papasmurf_error.log
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/papasmurf_access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

dav_svn.conf File:

```
<Location /svn/Code>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Code"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

I think that should be enough of a word vomit - I hope someone has an idea of what is going on... I sure don't. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have any information in the server logs? Is it intentional that you have both a `<directory>` and a `<location>` block for `/svn/TSAACode`?

Comment: Both the access.log and the error.log are empty. The `<directory>` and `<location>` blocks are left-overs from the initial copy of the default file. Truth be told, I don't know if both or which one of the two is required...

Comment: Heh, I bet Apache doesn't have write permission to `/etc/apache2/logs/`. (Which is probably a good idea. Logs belong in `/var/log/`.)

Comment: You are correct, I was looking at the wrong log files. I'll post their content in a bit.

Comment: In fact - now that I have the error messages I will take some time to figure this out instead of taking your time. I'll post in the morning.

Comment: I was also getting a 403 on svn checkout. I fixed it by deleting my `~/.subversion/` directory (I don't use subversion, so there was nothing important in there, you might want to move it rather than deleting it, in case you want to recover it later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Once I was looking at the correct error files (the Apache server error files in /var/log/apache2, not the site error files) I found the following error for each time I tried to do a checkout:

```
(2)No such file or directory: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]
```

and for each time I tried to point my browser to the repository I found this error:

```
Could not fetch resource information.  [403, #0]
```

Turns out, this is due to an error in the  line of the dav_svn.conf file; it should read as follows:

```
<Location /svn/>

DAV svn
SVNParentPath /svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Code"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth.htpasswd
Require valid-user
SSLRequireSSL

</Location>
```

By putting a lower directory in the location but a higher directory in the SVN Parent Path, I essentially created a contradicting statement which made the server unable to figure out what directory I was trying to look at. Also, the second "/" is important.

Thank you sarnold for pointing me toward the right error files!